# what is modulo addressing?

Tags: dsp, addressing

What exactly is modulo addressing? I think [here](https://microchipdeveloper.com/dsp0201:modulo-addressing) is a useful source but I can't understand what it is exactly about. From my understanding it implements a circular buffer.
Is it that? Why is that so important/special that it is a feature of a DSP?

Comment: not a circular buffer, per se ... imagine 10 buckets, numbered 0 to 9 .... imagine 240 golf balls, numbered 0 to 249 ... your task is to look at last digit on the golf ball and place the golf ball in corresponding bucket ... that's it, modulo 10 addressing

Comment: I think it is specifically beneficial to certain FFT operations where the index is used to select a multiplier. By implementing the modulo in HW it saves one operation per iteration. The reason to exist for DSP's is to perform operations related to FFT's. Speeding up FFT loops by one operation is significant.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want a buffer/list/array/whatever of 32 elements. You could do something like this:

```
index = 0
forever:
    store element at buffer_address + index
    index = index + 1
    if index > 31:
        index = 0
```

but doing a comparison and a possible jump can make it hard to efficiently pipeline your code. Instead you could use modulo 32 arithmetic for the index:

```
index = 0
forever:
    store element at buffer_address + index
    index = index + 1
    index = index & 0b11111
```

where `&` is a bitwise logical-and operation. Note that the constant value `0b11111` is just `32-1`. This code executes in the same amount of time and in the same order every time, so it is easier to pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is that so important/special that it is a feature of a DSP?

Because DSPs started out with vastly smaller transistor/gate budgets compared to majority of complex digital chips today. A modern desktop CPU can throw a million gates at the job of analyzing the instruction stream and detecting loops and predicting jumps accurately so that the jump cost is effectively null.

But back when, say, ADSP 2k was first introduced, the whole DSP had less transistors than Intel uses just to implement efficient branch prediction on a single core of a modern Intel Core CPU. On that DSP, you couldn't easily make the loops "free" without involving the user. And thus, it has explicit, user-controllable address generators that offer circular addressing and step sizes larger than 1 as a configurable feature.

In other words, this feature is necessary to extract maximum performance out of the hardware, and is present even on non-DSP "generic" desktop-class processors - at a much bigger cost.